# Update EmailSubject and EmailMessage in Cloud Formation config file

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

Anyone know if I can set the Email Subject and Email Message fields in my cloud formation template config file?
[image]

It appears in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html) that those fields are not available.

Answer (score 7):

There you go:

```
Resources:
  CognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: ${self:custom.service}-${self:custom.stage}-UserPool
      AdminCreateUserConfig:
        InviteMessageTemplate: 
          EmailMessage: "Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}." 
          EmailSubject: "Your temporary password"
```

There is a whole documentation about configuring it using CloudFormation
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-invitemessagetemplate.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-invitemessagetemplate-emailmessage

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found it under [AdminCreateUserConfig -> InviteMessageTemplate section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-admincreateuserconfig-invitemessagetemplate.html)